# how to set value to external javascript variable from dojo module

Tags: dojo

I have a requirement in project that I have to expose some values inside dojo module to outside JavaScript functions.I want to do something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var  outvar="AAAA";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (ready, parser ) {
            ready(function () {  
               //WANT to access outside variable 'outvar' over here

             });
         });
</script>
```

Any Suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's different scopes so you won't be able to access it that way, but you can try to set global variable as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.outvar="AAAA";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/kernel", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (ready, parser, kernel ) {
            ready(function () {  
                console.log(kernel.global.outvar);
             });
         });
</script>
```